# What's the best way to query this data with Django ORM?

Tags: sql, django

I have a model like this:

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tasks_by_me')
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tasks_assigned_to_me')
```

And i want to fetch "**all tasks (without duplicates) that were either created by TheUser or assigned to Him**".

Here's a way i might code this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 as created_by_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 2 as created_by_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 3 as created_by_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS id, 2 as created_by_id
  ) task
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT 1 AS task_id, 1 AS user_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS task_id, 2 AS user_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS task_id, 1 AS user_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS task_id, 2 AS user_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS task_id, 3 AS user_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS task_id, 3 AS user_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS task_id, 2 AS user_id
  ) task_assignees ON task_assignees.task_id = task.id AND COALESCE(task_assignees.user_id, 2) = 2
WHERE task.created_by_id = 2
OR    task_assignees.user_id = 2;
```

Output:

```
id  created_by_id   task_id     user_id
1   1               1           2
2   2               2           2
4   2               4           2
```

**Note**: there's only 1 row for `task_id=2` despite the fact that it has 3 assignees and the task was created by `TheUser(id=2)`

I'm interested in what's the best practice to handle those scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/) for using django orm model instead of writing raw sql queries. The below example would give you the queryset where you have task assigned to you or task created by you. `Q` is used for performing complex queries in django orm

```
from django.db.models import Q
Task.objects.filter(Q(assignees__username='soemeusername') | Q(created_by__username='someusername')).distinct()
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! Don't you now if it's possible to construct the same sql as i provided or it has no real benefits versus the DISTINCT version?

Comment: The purpose of orm is to save you from the complexities of raw sql queries and performing big joins like you did either way the statement above mentioned will converted to almost same logic sql query like you mentioned.